# Test app will crash several days after build on my iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

I am developing iOS application.It performance is not bad. But this app will crash several days after build on my iPhone.
I have not registered Apple Developer Program, but this app's provisioning profile is not expired.

On Xcode, I found error logs when the app crashed. Details are as follows.(`****-****` mean as my name)

```
failed to get pid for label UIKitApplication:****-****.multiplication[1611][rb-legacy] : No such process (3)

Failed to start job for application<****-****.multiplication>: <NSError: 0x10275df30; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
        RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:****-****.multiplication[1611][rb-legacy];
    }
}

Launchd says label UIKitApplication:****-****.multiplication[1611][rb-legacy] has never exited

Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1156b4eb0; application<****-****.multiplication>:-1> with error: <NSError: 0x280b13a50; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; reason: "The launchd job couldn't be started."> {
    underlyingError = <NSError: 0x2814cda70; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
        userInfo = {
            RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
            RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:****-****.multiplication[1611][rb-legacy];
        }
    };
}

No exit context returned for failed launch! <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1156b4eb0; application<****-****.multiplication>:-1>
```

I want to solve this problems but I have been studying swift only for three month, I cant understand what I should check where.

Finally, thank you for your thinking for this question what written in poor English.

Comment: My app will be run properly for a few days.(But I’m not sure how many days it could not run). thank you for your comment!

Comment: apps installed via xcode without a developer program will stop running after a few days, they are only meant for development/testing.

Comment: Yes.But my app's provisioning profile is not expired. now my app on my iPhone can not run, but it's built yesterday.

Comment: xcode to device builds are temporary and will stop working at some point. not sure of the exact timescale, but it will stop working, i have seen it many times before.

Comment: OK. I'll complete my program first. If it was rejected because of it, I will ask again. Thank you so much!